# inline assembly segmentation fault

Tags: c, assembly, rot13

all,

I was trying to write a rot13 with inline assembly function...

the following code works with 'a', but when c goes to 'z', it doesn't work anymore...

and... it always shows "segmentation fault" ... Please give me some advice to solve

this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define add(a,b)\
asm volatile(\
    "add %%ebx,%%eax" \
    :"=a"(a) \
    :"a"(a),"b"(b) \
)

#define rot13(a)\
asm (\
"rot:\n\t"\
    "add $13,%%eax\n\t"\
    "cmpl $64,%%eax\n\t"\
    "jle L5f\n\t"\
    "cmpl $90, %%eax\n\t"\
    "jg L5f\n\t"\
    "cmpl $90,%%eax\n\t"\
    "jle L5f\n\t"\
    "subl $26,%%eax\n\t"\
"L5f:\n\t"\
    "cmpl $96,%%eax\n\t"\
    "jle L6f\n\t"\
    "cmpl $122,%%eax\n\t"\
    "jg L6f\n\t"\
    "cmpl $122,%%eax\n\t"\
    "jle L6f\n\t"\
    "subl $26,%%eax\n\t" \
"L6f:\n\t"\
    "leave\n\t"\
    :"=r"(a)\
    :"r"(a)\
)

int main()
{
    int a=13, b=12,c='z';
    rot13(c);
    printf("c-> rot13= %c\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a LEAVE instruction in your inline assembly? That will modify the stack pointer, as well as popping 4 bytes from the stack. It should only be present at the end of a function, and will be added by the compiler when needed.

Comment: thank you very much... still learn how to deal with inline assembly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your segmentation fault is because you have a `leave` instruction in there.  Inline assembly does *not* get called like a normal function, so you don't need that, and it'll mangle the stack.

Another problem is that you have all your assembly hardcoded to operate on `%eax`, but you didn't tell the compiler that.  It thinks it can stick the input in any register it wants and read the output back from any *other* register it wants.  It's possible to adapt the code to that by using `%0` and `%1` instead of `%%eax` all the time, but it's probably easier to change the input and output constraints to

```
asm ( <your code here> : "=a" (a) : "0" (a) )
```

which means "the output of this inline assembly must be in `%eax`, and the input must be in the same register as the output".  (If you put "a" again on the input constraint it will *not* work correctly.  GCC's register allocator is a 28-year-old pile of hacks upon hacks and you have to play by its rules.  The rules may be found in the "[Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)" and "[Constraints for Asm Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Constraints.html)" sections of the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/index.html); read them *very carefully*, including all subsections of the second section, and keep in mind that this is actually a repurposed feature of the internal "machine description" language and is optimized for that.)

This still doesn't give me the right *answer* for rot13('z'), but I think the remaining problems are bugs in your rot13 algorithm rather than in its interface with the rest of the program.